# How to select all elements that don't have a class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to select the elements that don't have a class (but may have an ID), the following

`$(".entry-container ul:not([class])").addClass("list type-1");`
 works fine.

If I want to select the elements that don't have an ID (but may have a class) the following

`$(".entry-container ul:not([id])").addClass("list type-1");` 
works fine.

But what if I want to select all the elements that don't have a class AND and an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".entry-container ul:not([id],[class])").addClass("list type-1");
```

Comment: that don't have a class AND id, not class OR id, so i'd remove the comma

Comment: Guess it depends on how you interpret it. None of those elements have a class AND an id, so i'd expect all three to be selected. http://jsfiddle.net/6MDUK/2/

Comment: @KevinB yeah true i interpreted it the other way around... Question title is conflicting with statement in the question...

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".entry-container ul").not("[id][class]").addClass("list type-1");
```

Using `.filter()` method:

```
$(".entry-container ul").filter(function() {
   return this.id === '' && this.className === '';
});
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not paranoia if they really *are* out to get you..! ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't test it in all browsers, I trimmed them in case that some browsers (like IE) treat them differently.

Answer (score 1):

see these:
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/css-boolean-selectors/

```
$(".entry-container ul:not([class]) .entry-container ul:not([id])").addClass("list type-1");
```